# Is there a way to build a horizontal compass in TypeScript & React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, compass

I am currently working on a webapplication in TypeScript/React.
Right now I am looking for a way to build a horizontal compass like this:
https://imgur.com/gallery/vPg7sF3/comment/1382565763

I have a number in degrees where the compass should point at

I have no clue where to start

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse this can be done, but it depends on your expectations. One implementation would be to track the letters separately (e.g. with only north implemented: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sutherland-1e8pv)
and add equivalent logic for the other directions, that would decide when to show each letter. For North it make sense to show it for `coordinate` inside of the 180 deg radius(thus width 180px of compass, for simplicity) that makeup "half of the compass" that you would see, looking from the side as your image shows.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, the browser API has been changed a lot. There is a react package [react-world-compass](https://npmjs.com/package/react-world-compass) solving this problem nicely.

A workable demo is [here](https://react-world-compass.chunlaw.io/).